# IE doesn't show the full picture

Tags: lumia, internet-explorer

[image]

This is how it shows pictures :( how can i fix this problem

Comment: Which OS are you using? This seems to be fixed in WP8.1 Update 1

Answer (score 4):

This is a Facebook web server misconfiguration. I had it to, like every other WP. it comes from the incompatibility of the web browser detection. Instead of getting the Site for "Mobile IE" most servers don't understand this Info when it gets from phone to the server.. I found no workaround except using the "Desktop Mode" which only "says": Hey there I'm not a cell phone, I am a real desktop-browser. 
In WP 8.1 its a way better. They taught the mobile IE to say: hey there im an android and voila you get a working site.

So in conclusion its a error from the web standards: your phone is not broken. Apple and Android made there own "standards" thats why so many sites on WP look that much awful...

BTW: The Facebook App for WP is quite good now, it got a real lift and is now more usable than ever before. give it a try ;)

I hope I could help you :)